# Use path alias as contextual filter

Tags: views, nodes, path-aliases

I have nodes in Drupal for News Articles that generates this automatic URL alias.

> [image: screenshot]

I also have a view for *News* nodes.

> [image: screenshot]

This is the data.

> [image: screenshot]

The problem is that I can't use *Content: Path (url)* or *Content: Path (Path)* as contextual filter.

*sync/newslist/1234*, where 1234 is node ID, works. I would like to pass the path or the URL to the contextual filter, so that *sync/newslist/world-first-chart-alerts-non-artists* will return that node.

Comment: This is not a contextual filter issue. The problem is you never reach the View via the path alias because it doesn't match. You could write your own path processor for the partial match or try a contrib module like https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example create a custom ViewsArgumentValidator and transform the given alias to the Node ID.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\argument_validator;

use Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument_validator\ArgumentValidatorPluginBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Validates whether an alias is a valid node alias and transform it to the nid.
 *
 * @ViewsArgumentValidator(
 *   id = "node_alias",
 *   title = @Translation("Node ID by alias")
 * )
 */
class NodeAlias extends ArgumentValidatorPluginBase {

  /**
   * The alias manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected $aliasManager;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('path_alias.manager'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateArgument($argument) {
    // Prepend slash.
    $argument = '/' . ltrim($argument, '/');
    $path = $this->aliasManager->getPathByAlias($argument);

    if (preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
      $this->argument->argument = $matches[1];
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }

}
```

In the **validateArgument** function we are checking if an internal path for a node can be found with that alias and transform the given argument to the corresponding Node ID.

Add this file named **NodeAlias.php** to you custom module in **src/Plugin/views/argument_validator** directory and clear the cache.

After that, you can use the **Content: Nid** contextual filter and select in the "When the filter value is in the URL or a default is provided" section the new Validator **Node ID by alias**.

[image]